# How to aligne image to text? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

How to make the coffee image close to the text?[example as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPjmr.png)

[how did I manage to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vat2U.png)

```css
.cup {
  float: right;
}

.mbc {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page1">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="mbc">Make better<br>coffee<img src="Coffe.png" alt="Coffe image" width="70px" height="67px" class="cup"></h1>
      <p>why learn how to blog?</p>
    </div>
    <img src="Croods.png" alt="Croods" width="476px" height="323px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, float right makes the image always go to the right side. If the image is positioned inline (display: inline, which is the default value), the image would be placed correctly.

```html
<h1>This is<br/>your text<img width="30" style="margin-left: 10px" src="https://hotemoji.com/images/dl/d/coffee-emoji-by-twitter.png" /></h1>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Additionally you can use the transform->translate property to correctly position the coffee image. Using margin-top for example can cause some problems in the positioning.